# If $f:A\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ bounded, $f(x)\geq 0$, for all $\epsilon>0$ exist P s.t. $S(f,P)<\epsilon$ then $f$ integrable, $\int_A f=0$

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

> **Problem:** Given $f:A\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ a bounded function, $f(x)\geq 0$. Prove that if for all $\epsilon>0$ exist P partition such that $S(f,P)<\epsilon$ then $f$ is integrable and $\int_A f=0$.

I know that $S(f,P)=\sum_{i_1,...,i_n} f(\xi_{i_1,..,i_n})\mu(R_{i_1,...,i_n}) $ where $\mu(R_{i_1,...,i_n})$ is the "volume" of the n dimensional cube (generated by the partition) and $\xi_{i_1,..,i_n}\in R_{i_1,...,i_n}$. I dont know how to start, maybe via contradiction but i really don't see clearly how to procced.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What "definition" of "integrable" you use?

Answer (score 1):

This is false for Riemann integrals. Take $A = [0,1]$ and let $f$ be a Dirichlet function (taking the value $1$ at rational points and $0$ at irrational points).

For any partition $P$ we can select irrational intermediate points such that $S(P,f) = 0$.  Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is some partition and Riemann sum such that $S(P,f) < \epsilon$. However, $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

I suspect you are missing some other hypotheses.

Comment: Is there a difference if the function is from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Raul_MFer:  No, we can construct a similar counterexample.  Now if we have that there is an upper (Darboux) sum $U(P,f) < \epsilon $ for every $\epsilon$ then this is true.